# How to remove a list of lists from another list of lists in R?

Tags: r

I have a two lists of lists generated by the following function:

```
 a <- replicate(10, sample(1:100,size=10), simplify=FALSE)
 b <- replicate(10, sample(1:100,size=10), simplify=FALSE)
```

Is there a way to remove numbers in 'b' lists from corresponding lists in 'a'
so if:

```
a[1] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
b[1] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
```

then the output would ideally be

```
c[1] = {1}
```

I was trying to do something like this but it didn't work:

```
for(i in 1:10){
index <- which( names(a[i]) %in% b[i])
a[i][-index]
}
```

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` with `setdiff`

```
Map(setdiff, b, a)
```

If it is the opposite

```
Map(setdiff, a, b)
```

Or another option is `vsetdiff` to preserve duplicate elements

```
library(vecsets)
Map(vsetdiff, a, b)
```

Or use `%in%` and negate (`!`)

```
Map(function(x, y) x[!x %in% y], a, b)
```

---

Or using `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(a)) a[[i]] <- a[[i]][!a[[i]] %in% b[[i]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

additional solution

```
a <- list(c(1:10))
b <- list(c(2:11))

purrr::map2(.x = a, .y = b, .f = dplyr::setdiff)
```